# How to check update log for apps on the phone

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-2

I am suspecting one of the app update causing a problem on my Galaxy S2 after I did a app update (about 15 apps) through Android Market. Is there a way to find out the app updating history (dates/app names/versions)?

Answer (score 3):

Go to your web browswer - not on the phone - use a desktop or laptop (you might be able to do this via phone but haven't checked - you would probably need desktop mode if you wanted to try) - and go to the Android Market: https://market.android.com/
Log in
Between the Search bar and Android Market you should get the following options Apps, Books, Movies and My Library - click on My Library.
Just under the search option you should see Purchase History. Click on it.
You should find a list of the apps and when they installed. This will help you pick up any apps etc that are new.

To see the most recently updated apps just go to the Market app on your phone, go to my apps (my downloads - depending on the version of your app market) and it will list them in the most recent order of updated/installed - with any requiring an update at the top - scroll past these to see the last ones you updated (if any has an error its possible it might be in the apps to update).

Comment: this is so helpful. However, my Market app on the phone sorts my apps in alphabetic and it seems there is no way to sort by updated date.

Comment: You are correct the latest version of the market no longer keeps last updated, so this would only apply to older versions of the market. Have confirmed this as updated to new version of the market today and see that is the case after updating some apps.

Comment: It's annoying that I cannot revert market app back to older version. Whenever I delete (it's actually deleting the update files) the market app in application management and launch market, the market app will update itself immediately.